# Raspberry pi won’t run Noobs installation

Tags: boot-issues

I bought a preinstalled sdcard with noobs, due to my manually created noobs sd not working and still have same problem with the pi. Without the sdcard it boots fine to the boot loader screen but when I turn it on with the noobs sd inserted it stay looping and only flashing a blue screen for a instant.

Comment: Which Operating System are you actually after?

Comment: Too be honest anything at the point, Rasbian os would be nice but I’m not picky.

Comment: In that case use the Raspberry Pi Imager to flash Raspberry Pi OS to your sd card. Don’t bother with Noobs.

Comment: Ok I’ll try it I’ll give an update soon if it works or not

Comment: Nope that didn’t work either same problem

Comment: @sking, could you edit your post to add an update on what you have already tried? That way people won't suggest things that you know haven't worked in your case :)

Answer (score -1):

Ok I actually got it too run the problem was actually the screen I’m using for it ([https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07XBVF1C9](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XBVF1C9)) I took out the adapter connecting the screen to the pi and plug the pi in with the adapter piece and while the pi plugged in I plugged the adapter in and like magic the pi is running!

Comment: It's hard to read. Can you please write some proper sentences with punctuation?